# How to use config.add_settings({'pyramid.includes': ...}) from included callable

Tags: python, config, settings, pyramid

When I created a default pyramid app from a cookie cutter, it resulted in an INI file with sections like this:

```
[app:myapp]
use = egg:myproject#myapp
pyramid.reload_templates = true
pyramid.debug_authorization = false
pyramid.debug_notfound = false
pyramid.debug_routematch = false
pyramid.default_locale_name = en
pyramid.includes = pyramid_debugtoolbar
```

Now I'm experimenting with adding these same settings in python code instead, using the `Configurator` object in `__init__.py`, and I find that the following appears to work the same:

```
config.include('pyramid_debugtoolbar')
config.add_settings({
    'pyramid.reload_templates'      : 'true',
    'pyramid.debug_authorization'   : 'false',
    'pyramid.debug_notfound'        : 'false',
    'pyramid.debug_routematch'      : 'false',
    'pyramid.default_locale_name'   : 'en',
    'pyramid.includes'              : 'pyramid_debugtoolbar',
    })
```

But when applying these setting in python, the first line `config.include('pyramid_debugtoolbar')` is required or it doesn't work. Yet, in the INI version, it's sufficient to set `pyramid.includes = pyramid_debugtoolbar`.

**After Further Digging**

Looking higher up the stack in my code, I found that the setting does work this way...

```
def main(global_config, **settings):
    """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application."""
    settings.update({'pyramid.includes':'pyramid_debugtoolbar'}) # SETTING HERE WORKS!
    with Configurator(settings=settings) as config:
        config.include(common_config)
        config.include('.routes')
        config.scan()

    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

But **NOT** this way...

```
def main(global_config, **settings):
    """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application."""
    with Configurator(settings=settings) as config:
        config.add_settings({'pyramid.includes':'pyramid_debugtoolbar'}) # NO EFFECT!
        config.include(common_config)
        config.include('.routes')
        config.scan()

    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

In the [documentation for pyramid.config](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/config.html#pyramid.config.Configurator.include), I found this warning that I suspect is what I'm dealing with:

> A configuration callable should be a callable that accepts a single
>   argument named config, which will be an instance of a Configurator.
>   However, be warned that it will not be the same configurator instance
>   on which you call this method. The code which runs as a result of
>   calling the callable should invoke methods on the configurator passed
>   to it which add configuration state. The return value of a callable
>   will be ignored.

In an effort to guess at the solution, I tried wrapping my `config.add_settings(...)` with various combinations of `config.commit()` and `config.begin()`/`config.end()`, and none of those worked either.

**My Question:**

How do I use `config.add_settings(...)` to set `pyramid.includes`? I want to do this in a `common_config()` callable that is included by multiple pyramid apps.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I add a link to the documentation for reference. According to the documentation, it should work just fine: https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/environment.html#pyramid-includes-vs-pyramid-config-configurator-include

Comment: Thanks for the link, @sinoroc, that helped me find where to dig in more, and I have now made edits/additions to my question that hope is easier to figure out.

Comment: Maybe the _WSGI application_ should be built within the _context manager_, i.e. `app = config.make_wsgi_app()` within the `with Configurator(...) as config` clause. Could that make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

The `pyramid.*` settings are used by the `Configurator`'s constructor. This means they need to be set prior to passing `Configurator(settings=settings)`. You can simply modify those settings first, then pass them to the configurator.